# Django steps or process messages via REST

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

For learning purpose I want to implement the next thing:

I have a script that runs selenium for example in the background and I have some log messages that help me to see what is going on in the terminal.
But I want to get the same messages in my REST request to the Angular app.

```
print('Started')
print('Logged in')
...
print('Processing')
...
print('Success')
```

In my view.py file

```
class RunTask(viewsets.ViewSet):
queryset = Task.objects.all()

@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], name='Run Test Script')
def run(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    task = task()

    if valid['success']:
        return Response(data=task)
    else:
        return Response(data=task['message'])
```

---

```
 def task()
    print('Staring')
    print('Logged in')
    ...
    print('Processing')
    ...
    print('Success')

    return {
        'success': True/False,
        'message': 'my status message'
    }
```

Now it shows me only the result of the task. But I want to get the same messages to indicate process status in frontend.
And  I can't understand how to organize it.

Or how I can tell angular about my process status?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not *that* simple. Indeed, the REST API lets you start the task, but since it runs in the same thread, the HTTP request will block until the task is finished before sending the response. Your `print` statements won't appear in the HTTP response but on your server output (if you look at the shell where you ran `python manage.py runserver`, you'll see those `print` statements).

Now, if you wish to have those output in real-time, you'll have to look for WebSockets. They allow you to open a "tunnel" between the browser and the server, and send/receive messages in real-time. The [django-channels library](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) allow you to implement them.

---

However, for long-running background tasks (like a Selenium scraper), I would advise to look into the [Celery task queue](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html). Basically, your Django process will schedule task into the queue. The tasks into the queue will then be executed by one (or more !) "worker" processes. The advantage of this is that your Django process won't be blocked by the long task: it justs add some work into the queue and then respond.

When you add tasks in the queue, Celery will give you a unique identifier for this task, that you can return in the HTTP response. You can then very well implement another endpoint which takes a task id in parameter and return the state of the task (is it pending ? done ? failed ?).

For this to work, you'll have to setup a "broker", a kind of database that will store the tasks to do and their results (typically RabbitMQ or Redis). Celery documentation explains this well: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/index.html

Either way you choose, it's not a trivial thing and will need quite some work before having some results ; but it's interesting to see how it expands the possibilities of a classical HTTP server.